# Constructing Context Free Grammar

Tags: formal-languages, computability, context-free

I am stuck and having a hard time with this question. I want to construct a CFG for the language $$L = \{{a^lb^mc^n | l,m\in N, n=|l-m|\}}$$
I know that the language consists of strings where:

1. number of a's = number of b's, so c=0

2. number of a's more than number of b's, c=l-m

3. number of a's less than number of b's, c=-(l-m)

I started with
$$S->ab$$
$$S->aSb$$
This generates all of case one, where number of a's = number of b's and c=0. I know that I could increment a's and c's by having aSc but I cant put that in the second line because it could generate a(aSc)b which is not in the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: try to do each language separately, and then your final grammar is S->S1|S2|S3.

To do your case 2, you can write

$S->aSc|X$

$X->aXb|\epsilon$.

I.e. you start by generating the c's and the exceeding a's, and then you generate the b's and the remaining a.

Comment: Note that we usually try and not enable people who try and have their homework done for them.